# Running a java program on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, arm

I want to use my pi as a navigation and weather station on my boat. One of the programs I need is JWX.jar. When I try to execute it, I type "java -jar JWX.jar", wich works flawlesly in Linux Mint and x86. But on Raspbian I get:

Java -version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1, mixed mode)"
```

Java -jar JWX.jar:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at jwx.ComboBoxController.set_value(ComboBoxController.java:153)
at jwx.ComboBoxController.populate_combobox(ComboBoxController.java:69)
at jwx.ComboBoxController.setup(ComboBoxController.java:52)
at jwx.ComboBoxController.<init>(ComboBoxController.java:41)
at jwx.JWX.setup_values(JWX.java:264)
at jwx.JWX.<init>(JWX.java:101)
at jwx.JWX.lambda$main$8(JWX.java:963)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Add the complete output of these commands: `java -version` - `java -jar JWX.jar`.

Comment: Have you initialized your ComboBoxController ? it is not a problem related to the RPi but a Java code problem.

Comment: What is JWX? Compare the Java installations between your Mint and Raspbian. Perhaps it assumes additional system libraries, like JavaFX. Try to find the source code of JWX or contact the authors of the software.